# Function can send ETH without using payable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, payable

I understand that a function must be declared as `payable` in order to send ETH to some address.

I am trying this piece of code using Solidity 0.7.1

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract SendMoney {

uint public balanceReceived; 

function sendETHToSmartContract() public payable {
    balanceReceived += msg.value;
}   

function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

function sendETHOutToCaller() public {
    msg.sender.transfer(getBalance());   
}
}
```

I declared `function sendETHOutToCaller()` without `payable`. When I run it , I can call `function sendETHOutToCaller()` to transfer the ETH from smart contract to the caller. Works fine on Solidity 0.7

Why in this case I am able to transfer the ETH from smart contract to the caller without `payable` ?

Answer (score 2):

Keyword `payable` in the function is needed to make the function able to receive ether. Sending ether is possible from any function, as long as the address sending is payable.